# Generate table only when updating numericInput in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

Can you help me with the following problem: I made an app that uses `Weighted Sum Method` (WSM) method in a given database. I can generate the final dataset normally, which is the `scaled` variable. Now I'm using this code together with Shiny, but notice that the weights of the two criteria I did manually (I considered 0.5 for both), however, I would like the code to recognize the values I insert in the two `numericInput`, instead of this way: `weights <- c(0.5,0.5)`.

Executable code below:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(dplyr)

df1<-structure(list(nclusters = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 
28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35), Coverage = c(0.0363201192049018, 
0.0315198954715543, 0.112661460735583, 0.112661460735583, 0.112661460735583, 
0.0813721071219816, 0.0862146652218061, 0.0697995564757394, 0.0599194966471805, 
0.0507632014547115, 0.052076958349629, 0.052076958349629, 0.052076958349629, 
0.052076958349629, 0.052076958349629, 0.052076958349629, 0.0410332568832433, 
0.0389940601722214, 0.0441742111970355, 0.0441742111970355, 0.0441742111970355, 
0.0438099091238968, 0.0409906284310306, 0.0409906284310306, 0.035480410134286, 
0.035480410134286, 0.035480410134286, 0.035480410134286, 0.035480410134286, 
0.035480410134286, 0.035480410134286, 0.0345381204372174, 0.0287729883480053, 
0.0287729883480053), Production = c(1635156.04305, 474707.64025, 
170773.40775, 64708.312, 64708.312, 64708.312, 949.72635, 949.72635, 
949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 
949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 
949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 
949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 
949.72635, 949.72635)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-34L))

weights <- c(0.5,0.5) 

scaled <- df1 |>
  mutate(Coverage = min(Coverage) / Coverage,
         Production = Production / max(Production))

scaled <- scaled |>
  rowwise() |>
  mutate(`Performance Score` = weighted.mean(c(Coverage, Production), w = weights))

scaled$Rank <- (nrow(scaled) + 1) - rank(scaled$`Performance Score`)

ui <- fluidPage(

    column(4,
         wellPanel(
           
  numericInput("weight1", label = h4("Weight 1"),
               min = 0, max = 1, value = ""),
  
  numericInput("weight2", label = h4("Weight 2"),
               min = 0, max = 1, value = ""),
  
  helpText("The sum of weights should be equal to 1"))),
  
  hr(),
  
  column(8,
         tabsetPanel(
           tabPanel("table", dataTableOutput('table'))))

)

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$weight1, {
    updateNumericInput(session, 'weight2',
                       value = 1 - input$weight1)
  })

  output$table <- renderDataTable({
  datatable (scaled,options = list(columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-center', targets = "_all")),
                                            paging =TRUE,searching = FALSE, pageLength =  10,dom = 'tip',scrollX=TRUE),
               rownames = FALSE) 
  
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply wrap your data munging in `reactive` - I've disabled the second input to avoid [circular references](https://mastering-shiny.org/action-dynamic.html#updating-inputs):

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
library(shinyjs)

df1 <- structure(list(nclusters = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14,
15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33,
34, 35), Coverage = c(0.0363201192049018, 0.0315198954715543,
0.112661460735583, 0.112661460735583, 0.112661460735583, 0.0813721071219816,
0.0862146652218061, 0.0697995564757394, 0.0599194966471805,
0.0507632014547115, 0.052076958349629, 0.052076958349629, 0.052076958349629,
0.052076958349629, 0.052076958349629, 0.052076958349629, 0.0410332568832433,
0.0389940601722214, 0.0441742111970355, 0.0441742111970355,
0.0441742111970355, 0.0438099091238968, 0.0409906284310306,
0.0409906284310306, 0.035480410134286, 0.035480410134286, 0.035480410134286,
0.035480410134286, 0.035480410134286, 0.035480410134286, 0.035480410134286,
0.0345381204372174, 0.0287729883480053, 0.0287729883480053), Production =
c(1635156.04305, 474707.64025, 170773.40775, 64708.312, 64708.312, 64708.312,
949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635,
949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635,
949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635,
949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635)),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-34L))

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  column(4,
         wellPanel(
           numericInput(
             "weight1",
             label = h4("Weight 1"),
             min = 0,
             max = 1,
             value = NA,
             step = 0.1
           ),
           disabled(numericInput(
             "weight2",
             label = h4("Weight 2"),
             min = 0,
             max = 1,
             value = NA,
             step = 0.1
           )),
           helpText("The sum of weights should be equal to 1")
         )),
  hr(),
  column(8,
         tabsetPanel(tabPanel(
           "table", DTOutput('table')
         ))))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  scaled <- reactive({
    weights <- c(req(input$weight1), req(input$weight2))
    
    scaled <- df1 |>
      mutate(Coverage = min(Coverage) / Coverage,
             Production = Production / max(Production))
    
    scaled <- scaled |>
      rowwise() |>
      mutate(`Performance Score` = weighted.mean(c(Coverage, Production), w = weights))
    
    scaled$Rank <- (nrow(scaled) + 1) - rank(scaled$`Performance Score`)
    
    scaled
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$weight1, {
    freezeReactiveValue(input, "weight2")
    updateNumericInput(session, 'weight2', value = 1 - input$weight1)
  })
  
  output$table <- renderDT({
    req(scaled())
    datatable(
      scaled(),
      options = list(
        columnDefs = list(list(
          className = 'dt-center', targets = "_all"
        )),
        paging = TRUE,
        searching = FALSE,
        pageLength =  10,
        dom = 'tip',
        scrollX = TRUE
      ),
      rownames = FALSE
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: That's right, thanks for the reply.  A question, in this example above, I used only one multicriteria method. But I'm going to use two more concurrently, that is, the person chooses the weights, and those weights are going to be the same for the three multi-criteria methods. My question is: do I need to do a `reactive` for the other two, like you did for `scaled`, only?

Comment: You could use a single `reactive` and return a list of results or you use a separate reactive for each "method" - both are reasonable aproaches as long as you aren't repeating code.

Comment: is there another resolution approach without inserting everything into `server`? I asked a question about this, if you can help.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71460905/approach-without-inserting-all-the-code-on-the-server