# Approach without inserting all the code on the server

Tags: r, shiny

The code below uses the `WSM` (Weighted Sum Method) method to generate a final ranking table. For this, it is necessary to select criteria weights. As it is in the code, I am choosing the criteria weights manually (`weights <- c(0.5,0.5)` ). In this sense, I made two `numericInput` for choosing the weights. One way to solve this is to put everything in a `reactive` on `server`, as answered here: [Generate table only when updating numericInput in a shiny app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71438908/generate-table-only-when-updating-numericinput-in-a-shiny-app)

However, I would like to see the possibility of not stripping the code referring to the WSM calculation on `server`, as it was done in the answer of the link I showed. In this case, this part of code:

```
weights <- c(0.5,0.5) 

scaled <- df1 |>
  mutate(Coverage = min(Coverage) / Coverage,
         Production = Production / max(Production))

scaled <- scaled |>
  rowwise() |>
  mutate(`Performance Score` = weighted.mean(c(Coverage, Production), w = weights))

scaled$Rank <- (nrow(scaled) + 1) - rank(scaled$`Performance Score`)
```

Therefore, is there any other solution approach?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(dplyr)

df1<-structure(list(nclusters = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 
28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35), Coverage = c(0.0363201192049018, 
0.0315198954715543, 0.112661460735583, 0.112661460735583, 0.112661460735583, 
0.0813721071219816, 0.0862146652218061, 0.0697995564757394, 0.0599194966471805, 
0.0507632014547115, 0.052076958349629, 0.052076958349629, 0.052076958349629, 
0.052076958349629, 0.052076958349629, 0.052076958349629, 0.0410332568832433, 
0.0389940601722214, 0.0441742111970355, 0.0441742111970355, 0.0441742111970355, 
0.0438099091238968, 0.0409906284310306, 0.0409906284310306, 0.035480410134286, 
0.035480410134286, 0.035480410134286, 0.035480410134286, 0.035480410134286, 
0.035480410134286, 0.035480410134286, 0.0345381204372174, 0.0287729883480053, 
0.0287729883480053), Production = c(1635156.04305, 474707.64025, 
170773.40775, 64708.312, 64708.312, 64708.312, 949.72635, 949.72635, 
949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 
949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 
949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 
949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 
949.72635, 949.72635)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-34L))

weights <- c(0.5,0.5) 

scaled <- df1 |>
  mutate(Coverage = min(Coverage) / Coverage,
         Production = Production / max(Production))

scaled <- scaled |>
  rowwise() |>
  mutate(`Performance Score` = weighted.mean(c(Coverage, Production), w = weights))

scaled$Rank <- (nrow(scaled) + 1) - rank(scaled$`Performance Score`)

ui <- fluidPage(

    column(4,
         wellPanel(
           
  numericInput("weight1", label = h4("Weight 1"),
               min = 0, max = 1, value = ""),

 selectInput("maxmin1", label = h5("Maximize or Minimize?"),
                       choices = list("","Maximize " = "+", "Minimize" = "-"), selected = NULL),
  
  numericInput("weight2", label = h4("Weight 2"),
               min = 0, max = 1, value = ""),
  
 selectInput("maxmin2", label = h5("Maximize or Minimize?"),
                       choices = list("","Maximize " = "+", "Minimize" = "-"), selected = NULL),
  helpText("The sum of weights should be equal to 1"))),
  
  hr(),
  
  column(8,
         tabsetPanel(
           tabPanel("table", dataTableOutput('table'))))

)

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$weight1, {
    updateNumericInput(session, 'weight2',
                       value = 1 - input$weight1)
  })

  output$table <- renderDataTable({
  datatable (scaled,options = list(columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-center', targets = "_all")),
                                            paging =TRUE,searching = FALSE, pageLength =  10,dom = 'tip',scrollX=TRUE),
               rownames = FALSE) 
  
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**This is the error that appears**

[image]

Comment: I don´t understand. Could you be more specific please!

Comment: @TarJae, thanks for reply. I've tweaked the question, if you can see. But basically, it's that I wouldn't want to insert the code referring to the WSM calculation on `server`, as was done in the answer to the link I put in the question. Is it more understandable now?

Comment: Just curious why you want to change this good strategy. Basically in the ui part there should be only code for the ui and all calculations should be done in the server part. This is essentially the basic of shiny framework (unless I missed something). So my advice is to stay with this strategy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function that takes the weights, and call that function in `eventReactive()` [There may be other ways to do this, also]

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(dplyr)

df1<-structure(list(nclusters = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
                                  12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 
                                  28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35), Coverage = c(0.0363201192049018, 
                                                                                0.0315198954715543, 0.112661460735583, 0.112661460735583, 0.112661460735583, 
                                                                                0.0813721071219816, 0.0862146652218061, 0.0697995564757394, 0.0599194966471805, 
                                                                                0.0507632014547115, 0.052076958349629, 0.052076958349629, 0.052076958349629, 
                                                                                0.052076958349629, 0.052076958349629, 0.052076958349629, 0.0410332568832433, 
                                                                                0.0389940601722214, 0.0441742111970355, 0.0441742111970355, 0.0441742111970355, 
                                                                                0.0438099091238968, 0.0409906284310306, 0.0409906284310306, 0.035480410134286, 
                                                                                0.035480410134286, 0.035480410134286, 0.035480410134286, 0.035480410134286, 
                                                                                0.035480410134286, 0.035480410134286, 0.0345381204372174, 0.0287729883480053, 
                                                                                0.0287729883480053), Production = c(1635156.04305, 474707.64025, 
                                                                                                                    170773.40775, 64708.312, 64708.312, 64708.312, 949.72635, 949.72635, 
                                                                                                                    949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 
                                                                                                                    949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 
                                                                                                                    949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 
                                                                                                                    949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 
                                                                                                                    949.72635, 949.72635)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-34L))
get_scaled <- function(w1,w2,m1,m2) {
  weights = c(w1,w2)
  method = list("-" = min,"+"=max)
  m1 = method[[m1]]
  m2 = method[[m2]]
  scaled <- df1 |>
    mutate(Coverage = m1(Coverage) / Coverage,
           Production = Production / m2(Production))
  
  scaled <- scaled |>
    rowwise() |>
    mutate(`Performance Score` = weighted.mean(c(Coverage, Production), w = weights))
  
  scaled$Rank <- (nrow(scaled) + 1) - rank(scaled$`Performance Score`)
  return(scaled)
}


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  column(4,
         wellPanel(
           
  numericInput("weight1", label = h4("Weight 1"),
               min = 0, max = 1, value = ""),

 selectInput("maxmin1", label = h5("Maximize or Minimize?"),
                       choices = list("","Maximize " = "+", "Minimize" = "-"), selected = NULL),
  
  numericInput("weight2", label = h4("Weight 2"),
               min = 0, max = 1, value = ""),
  
 selectInput("maxmin2", label = h5("Maximize or Minimize?"),
                       choices = list("","Maximize " = "+", "Minimize" = "-"), selected = NULL),
  helpText("The sum of weights should be equal to 1"))),  
  hr(),
  
  column(8,
         tabsetPanel(
           tabPanel("table", dataTableOutput('table'))))
  
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$weight1, {
    updateNumericInput(session, 'weight2',
                       value = 1 - input$weight1)
  })
  
    scaled <- reactive({
    get_scaled(input$weight1, input$weight2, input$maxmin1,input$maxmin2)
  })
  
  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    datatable (scaled(),options = list(columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-center', targets = "_all")),
                                     paging =TRUE,searching = FALSE, pageLength =  10,dom = 'tip',scrollX=TRUE),
               rownames = FALSE) 
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Thanks for answering. I know it wasn't a question for this question, but I have two alternatives either I make a new question or I adjust this question. I n fact I want to do exactly what you did however for the criteria direction too, which is the max and min. I inserted the `selecInput` into the code already of the question. I can ask a new question if you wish. Do you know how to adjust?

Comment: sure, I tried to add above in answer

Comment: Thanks for reply! Why appears this error:?
 `Problem with mutate() column Coverage.
[34mi[39m Coverage = m1(Coverage)/Coverage.
[31mx[39m could not find function "m1` Does it appear to you?

Comment: Using `eventReactive` instead of `reactive` in this case is making no sense - unless you like typing. Usually eventReactives are not dependent on all reactive expressions in their body - that's the usecase for this function. However you are listening on all inputs, so just use `reactive`.

Comment: I took exactly  your code above and ran it, but the same error as the message I said above continues to appear. For you corrected after you used `reactive`? After I select the criteria weights and directions, the table is generated correctly, but I'm just finding this message strange when I run the app. I inserted the error in the question.

Comment: @Antonio , that is becuase maxmin1 and maxmin2 are not initialized initially. I didn't know how you wanted to solve that - there are numerous ways. One way is to add `req(input@maxmin1)` and `req(input@maxmin2)` statements before calling `get_scaled()` within the reactive

Comment: Friends, do you know how to solve this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71468689/create-connection-between-numericinput-and-function-in-a-shiny-app
It is very similar to this one. The only difference is that I don't generate an output table. The WSM calculation helps to know the number of clusters.